# Ansible "nsupdate" module adding zone to record value

Tags: dns, ansible

I'm trying to use the [nsupdate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/nsupdate_module.html) module to update records but I'm having mixed success. While the records do get added, I'm getting the zone appended at the end of the value.

For example: 
I want a cname called `mycname.domain1.com` pointed to `shawarmas.domain2.com`.  After I run the playbook I end up with an entry that looks like this:

`mycname.domain1.com. 5     IN      CNAME   shawarmas.domain2.com.domain1.com`

Is there something wrong in my playbook that is causing this?

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: myserver

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ value }}"
  - name: "Add record to escapia zone"
    nsupdate:
      key_name: "ddns"
      key_secret: "******"
      server: "dnsserver"
      record: "{{ record }}"
      type: "{{ type }}"
      value: "{{ value }}"
      ttl: 5
```

Run Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inv -e "record=record-test.example.com. 
type=CNAME value=test.different.com" exampledns.yml -v
```

Ansible output:

```
changed: [myserver] => changed=true
  dns_rc: 0
  dns_rc_str: NOERROR
  record:
    record: record-test.example.com.
    ttl: 5
    type: CNAME
    value:
    - test.different.com
    zone: example.com.
```

DNS result:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
record-test.example.com. 5     IN      CNAME   test.different.com.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you need to append a `.` to the end of the value to make it full qualified. Without the `.` it is unqualified and appending the zone.

Try with:

```
ansible-playbook -i inv -e "record=record-test.example.com. type=CNAME value=test.different.com." exampledns.yml -v
```